# How to get __RequestVerificationToken Cookie without browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, cookies, antiforgerytoken

I have a Azure Cloud application using AntiforgeryFilters for preventing from CSRF. Now I have another C# WPF application from which I need to send a POST request to Azure App, but the problem is that every Post request has to be validate by AntiforgeryFilter and I need to know two things:

1. __RequestVerificationToken
2. __RequestVerificationToken Cookies

I figured out that I should send first time only simple GET Request and my Cloud App return to WPF App simple View containing __RequestVerificationToken . Now I do not know how can I figure out the problem with the __RequestVerificationToken cookies, because I am not using any browser.

Do I Have here any options how I can get the value of __RequestVerificationToken Cookies?

Thanks for all advice.

Comment: Have you tried to get `__RequestVerificationToken cookie` from the response of `GET` request that returns simple view containing `__RequestVerificationToken` ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan Get response only contains __RequestVerificationToken I also need cookie value

Comment: The response also should have Response Cookies. You can get them like this: `request.Cookies`